# Optional UInt8? gives 2 byte memory size

Tags: swift, option-type

UInt8 memory size is 1 byte . but when i make it optional value, it gives 2 byte of size.

```
   var serail : UInt8? = 255
    print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: serail)) // it gives 2 byte size.


        var serail : UInt8 = 255
        print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: serail)) // it gives 1 byte size.
```

how to get exactly 1 byte memory size for Integer value

Comment: Unwrap your optional

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, an optional is an enum and looks something like this:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case some(Wrapped)  // not nil
    case none  // nil
}
```

The symbols `?` and `!` are just shorthands for referring to this optional enum. This extra layer causes it to be 2 bytes large.

However, if you unwrap the optional, the returned value is the wrapped value itself, so it becomes 1 byte.